# white-space: pre-line adds unusal space at top

Tags: html, css

I've a below piece of css declaration which adds line spacing given in the below screenshot.

```
.colGroup{
    white-space: pre-line;
}
```

I've tried adding the below attributes but with no luck.

```
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: top;
height: 4.75em;
line-height: 1.75em;
```

**EDIT** (added part of the repeating `<td>` tag where I'm facing this issue).

```
<td width="15%">
    <span class="colGroup">
       <div>
            <p id="c2308view">
                t = 24 
                t1 = 27 
                t2 = 27 
                t3 = 36
                </p> 
            </div>
        </span>
        <span class="dateColumn">
            <div>
                <p id="c2312view"><span>31-Dec-2010</span></p>
            </div>
        </span>
</td>
```

Can someone help?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Show us your HTML code as well

Comment: Presumably because you _have_ extra whitespace there, that you didn’t notice previously, because of how it gets collapsed under normal circumstances …

Comment: @ItayGal Added. Thanks!

Comment: Where you used '.colGroup' selector in your markup?

Comment: @Hanif Sorry, Updated my html.. Please check.

Comment: Screenshots aren't really helpful without a reproducible example.  The thing to do here is add your html and css code to a snippet to demonstrate the problem.  Given your rep I assume you know how to do this.

Answer (score 20):

I just recently had to deal with the way various `white-space` values are handled within css. The documentation on MDN for white-space is very helpful. See this, and the entire page: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space#Values

***What does it mean when you use the following css?***

```
white-space: pre-line;
```

This will preserve line-breaks in your code, while collapsing white space. Line-breaks can be explict `<br/>` elements or newline characters.

**Look again at your code.** Notice, while you can't see character, you return three times before getting to the values within the `<p>` element. There is a hidden `newline` character being read by the DOM.

```
<span class="colGroup"> /* newline character 1 */
   <div> /* newline character 2 */
        <p id="c2308view"> /* newline character 3 */
            t = 24 /* newline character 4, which I assume you want to preserve */
```

If you remove these returns within your code, while the syntax is not all that readable, it will honor the `white-space` value you are desiring.

***See the snippet below:***

```css
.colGroup {
    white-space: pre-line;
}
```

```html
<td width="15%">
    <span class="colGroup"><div><p id="c2308view">t = 24 
t1 = 27 
t2 = 27 
t3 = 36</p></div></span>
    <span class="dateColumn">
        <div>
            <p id="c2312view">
                <span>31-Dec-2010</span>
            </p>
        </div>
    </span>
</td>
```

Comment: Great answer, learned something today!

Comment: Bless you, and all your children! I had difficulties with the pre space behaviour and the pre-line just fixed it. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 6):

try to add a `<span>` inside of the `<p>`, this did the trick for me.

For example with Tailwind.css and Vue.js:

```
<p class="whitespace-pre-line">
   <span>{{ user.info }}</span>
</p>
```

Comment: This didn't work for me. But adding a `negative margin-top` to `p` while `span` is inside of it did the trick. to be precise, the value of margin-top would be the same as the line-height of the element. `(ex: margin-top: -16px;)`

Answer (score -4):

I ran into this just yesterday. I did something like this:

```
.colGroup{
white-space: pre-line;
margin-top: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Hi Robby, Thanks for the reply. However I had no luck with this. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Do you have any styling for #c2308view set?